# Order posts by custom field

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have 2 types of posts - `event` and `news`. For `event` category, I have a custom field - `event_date` while `news` does not have that field.

I want to order the posts according to the `event_date`. I want to include the news to even though they don't have the `event_date` field.

I have tried with this:

```
$args = array(
    'cat'               => $categories,
    'posts_per_page'    => $display_count,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'number'            => $display_count,
    'page'              => $page,
    'offset'            => $offset,
    'meta_key'          => 'event_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This query does not return any of the news. Is this because the news don't have the order field? If so, then how can I solve this problem? I was thinking of ordering with multiple like-

```
'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num date'
```

but no luck.

Comment: Have you seen `'post_type' => 'post'` in the arguments array of your query? Set in this argument the posts types you want to get.

Comment: You will need to drop your `orderby` parameter and then just return your posts as normal. You will then need to sort the returned array of posts ($query->posts) with normal PHP sorting, preferably with `usort` to get the desired output